# Is there a relationship between visitor pattern and DeMorgan's Law?

Tags: data-structures, type-theory

Visitor Pattern enables mimicking sum types with product types. Where does the "sum"-iness come from?

For example, in OCaml one could define `type my_bool = True | False`

Or encode with visitor pattern:

```ocaml
type 'a bool_visitor = {
  case_true: unit -> 'a;
  case_false: unit -> 'a;
}

let t visitor = visitor.case_true () 
let f visitor = visitor.case_false ()
  
let visitor = {
  case_true = (fun () -> "true");
  case_false = (fun () -> "true");
} 
  
  
let () = print_endline (t visitor) (* prints "true" *)
```

What's the best way of explaining the sum-type-to-visitor-pattern transformation? Is it:

- Of course + and * are interdefinable, what did I expect?
- Or is it that the left side of `->` is the "negative" position and that this leads to a DeMorgan-law-like flip of sum and product?

I also wonder if this question is related to how one can use universally-quantified types to mimic existential types.

Comment: There's also a similar well-known transformation from sum type to product type: https://gist.github.com/mheiber/9b26c96d4019b7d50ae1153512096d2e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to explain it is
$$\mathsf{Bool} \to C \cong C \times C,$$
which is a special case of
$$(A + B) \to C \cong (A \to C) \times (B \to C).$$
Read the above as follows: as sum is equivalent to a pair of visitors.

(By the way, this is not the de Morgan law. It does not have a name, as far as I know. It's a general consequence of the definition of the concepts involved.)

Comment: I think you've given a nice restatement of the equivalence and I see how the equivalence is a consequence of the definitions if I read this as in Coq's `Prop`: https://gist.github.com/mheiber/872eddb8fdec21a8cb63b6a4d2710892.
Maybe my original question didn't make sense. I was trying to get an intuition - is it helpful to think of the left side of `->` as "negative" and that negativeness can flip things? A similar sort of thing seems to be happening with how existential types can be mimicked using nested universally-quanitifying functions.

Comment: By the way, I think the example I gave is more similar to your second formula: 
$$(True + False) \to string \cong (True \to string) \times (False \to string).$$

Comment: One way to view types is "combinatorically" -- you count their (total) inhabitants -- in which case discriminated sum types correspond to numeric sums, and product types correspond to numeric products. In such a scheme, function types correspond to numerical exponents (a "product" for each element of the domain). Combinatorically, the question then becomes
$$ C^{A+B} \stackrel{?}{=} C^A \cdot C^B $$

Comment: @MaxHeiber: the law holds in any cartesian closed category, and in particular in a Heyting algebra (which corresponds to your loking at `Prop`). Regarding the difference between `C` and `1 \to C` (which you write erroneously as $\mathrm{True} \to C$ and $\mathrm{False} \to C$ – wrong because $\mathrm{True}$ and $\mathrm{False}$ are not types but values), those two are again isomorphic.

Comment: @CurtisF, that's exactly what I was looking for, the exponential notation helped. I should have remembered $$C^{A+B} = C^A \cdot C^B$$ from high school math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties